# How to use 2 eventClick on 1 calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have these kind of code for eventClick which being used 2 times for update and delete an event on full calendar.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                      var title = prompt('Event Title:', calEvent.title, { buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false} });

                      if (title){
                          calEvent.title = title;
                          self.$el.fullCalendar('updateEvent',calEvent);
                      }
                      console.log(title);
            },

            eventClick: function(event){
                $(".closon").click(function() {
                    self.$el.fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
                });
            },
```

Notice that, i have 2 eventClick being used here which is one for edit, and one for delete purposes. The result for this code is nothing happen. Which means when i run on my chrome, it doesn't do both of these.

EDIT: My question is how to use 2 eventclick at 1 calendar?

Comment: Write in one function instead, object can not have several keys with same name

Comment: @karaxuna you mean that i have to create one function and inside the function got 2 eventClick? correct me if i misunderstood somewhere.

Comment: You [cannot initialize the calendar control](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) with 2 eventClick handlers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery on method to add couple listeners on one events.

as example

```
  $('#element-id').on('click', function1);
  $('#element-id').on('click', function2);
```

Answer (score 0):

My question is how to use 2 eventclick at 1 calendar?

If you mean that you click button A to invoke 2 click event functions of 2 other buttons then..

trigger...

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/